# Html changes are not updating in chrome only

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

So there is some kind of caching issue going on with chrome lately.
I updated an image on a web page, but it will not update in chrome. Other browsers are fine.
Also I'm going to note that I changed the html, and gave the image a new name to force browsers to grab the updated version.
i.e image.jpg > image-v1.jpeg

How on earth does chrome not grab the updated version of this?

Anyone seen this going on lately and know of a fix.
Thanks

Comment: Never met this issue even renamed the resource file name. Are you sure your chrome is showing the correct page or it's not running on something like staging site?

Comment: @Chaska definitly the correct site.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to settings I believe , we asked other staff members to load up the page and it always updates for them when the file name is changed. The user of affected computer doesn't want to restore chrome to default settings though because of loss of form information etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone stumped on this kind of an issue, if you are using a web farm check to make sure DFS replication across the servers is working correctly.
It was failing for one server in my case, this is why some users got the updated version while others didn't.

to verify if replication worked, log into the servers via RDP then check the last modified date time stamps for the file(s) in question.

Answer (score 1):

When you clear browsing data, make sure to check the box to clear cached images, also make sure the duration is set to "All time".

https://i.ibb.co/jzYk6DK/ex.png

If that doesn't work, try renaming the image.

If that also doesn't work, take a look at the web server configuration expiry headers, and check the duration for cached images in your format. It could be in .htaccess, or it could be elsewhere depending on if you're using apache2 or Nginx.

Comment: welcome someguy :) check my question I explained that I renamed the file. This should force all clients to download the new version. This should bypass all caching right? Kind of like adding a version string to the end of a css file

Comment: Renaming the file should definetely remove the caching of the old file. Try renaming the begining characters of the picture instead of the end, like ab.png should be dss.png.

Comment: I asked other staff to check the page and it updated for them.
Check my latest comment on question